# How to set fractional font size in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts

I'm trying to set the font in `gnome-terminal` to 9.5, which is ideal for me. I have installed many programming fonts, viz. proggy, anonymous-pro, terminus, inconsolata, droid-monovar, consolas, gohu, anka-coder, termsyn and montecarlo).

I have tried the terminals GNOME Terminal, Konsole and Xfce4 Terminal, but none of them seem to make available the "9.5pt" size (or any other fractional size) for any font.

Is the problem with my fonts or my terminal?

Comment: 9.5 is very small. I'm not sure if this is *ideal* for you. I prefer larger fonts. Using gnome terminal for example it is easy to user a larger font size when typing using `Ctrl +` and a smaller if I want to get an overview over a file: `Ctrl -`

Comment: @hek2mgl A lot of programmers tend to prefer smaller fonts (from the screenshots I've seen). 9.5pt is ideal for me because it allows 3 Vim windows side-by-side of Python files (PEP8 compliance means the max line length is 79), but 10pt doesn't.

Comment: The fonts in screenshots might be looking smaller, because the author wanted to get as much content as possible onto the screenshot (However, it is just a guess).. What about using 3 tabs in one vim as an alternative? Also you might use `screen` and create `2 two vertical splits, and 1 horizontal split below them` (You know what I mean?)

Comment: @hek2mgl Many of the programming fonts, like MonteCarlo and Termsyn, don't even have a size bigger than 10. I appreciate you trying to help me, but multiple Vim tabs and horizontal splits is much less comfortable than having 3 vertical splits (I know this because it's how I used to work before).